# Show that $n$ is $o(\log n)$

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

The question is to determine whether $$n \in o(\log n)$$

I know that we are trying to prove whether or not this is true, using  the definition of little-o notation:

$\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists x_0 \text{ such that } \forall x \geq x_0, \space n < \varepsilon \cdot \log n$

I have rearranged to $2^n < \varepsilon \cdot n$

But I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Vice versa, $\log n\in o(n)$ because l'Hopital had said that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log n}{n}=0$

Comment: Your intuition should already tell you that n grows much faster than log(n), so the statement is clearly false. If your intuition did not tell you this right away, you should develop more intuition about logarithms (and potentially other functions commonly appearing in mathematics).

Comment: @TMM my intuition told me that, my question is how to phrase it. "It is clearly false" is unfortunately not a valid proof

Comment: You wrote "we are trying to prove whether or not this is true." Next time just add that you already know it is false so we also know what your thoughts are.

Answer (score 2):

You can disprove the statement through the application of L'Hopital's rule.

Consider 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x}{\log x} $$

By applying L'Hopital's rule, we find
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x}{\log x} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(x)^{'}}{(\log x)^{'}}
$$

Thus as 
$$ \frac{d}{dx} x = 1 $$ and $$\frac{d}{dx} \log x = \frac{1}{x}$$
 we find:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac {x}{\log x} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}} = \lim_{x\to\infty} x = \infty
$$
Thus by the definition of a limit:
$$
\forall {c} \in{\mathbb{R}^+}, \space \exists x_0 \text { s.t } \forall{x} > x_0, \space \frac {x}{\log x} > c
$$ 
Rearranging gives $ {x} > c \cdot {\log x} $, which implies:
$$
\lnot \space \forall {c} > 0, \space \exists x_0 \text { s.t } \forall{x} > x_0, \space \space  {{x} \le c \cdot {\log x}}
$$
Thus we can conclude:
$$
n \notin o(\log n)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Considering the function $x\mapsto \log (x)-\sqrt {x} $,
It is easy to prove that for enough great $n $, we have

$$\log(n)<\sqrt {n}$$
then

$$\frac{n}{\log (n)}>\sqrt {n} $$

thus $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac {n}{\log (n)}=+\infty $$ and $n\notin o (\log (n)) $.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: instead of $x_0$ for this case you must read: for all $\epsilon>0$ exists $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $$n<\epsilon\cdot\log n,\quad n\ge N$$

or equivalently

$$\frac{n}{\log n}<\epsilon,\quad n\ge N>1$$

Comment: Thanks - but I don't understand what you have to do next? $n$ is bigger than $\log n$ as n increases, but where from there?

Comment: Choose, by example, $\epsilon=1$ but observe that $\frac2{\log 2}>1$ and for any $n>2$ we have that $\frac{n}{\log n}>1$. Just remember that $$\log n=x\iff e^x=n\iff x<n$$ for $n\in\Bbb N$ because $e>2$